# Could not find a declaration file for module '@editorjs/image'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, editorjs

I am using editorjs in my project and there are no typescript files in my project.
Could not find a declaration file for module '@editorjs/image'. 'node_modules/@editorjs/image/dist/bundle.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/editorjs__image` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@editorjs/image';`ts(7016)
No quick fixes are available. The typescript package is not available and when I am creating .d.ts file in the project
`declare module "@editorjs/image"`
but it is not referring to the editorjs/image package for the usage.

Comment: Have you tried running this command: npm i --save-dev @types/editorjs__image

Comment: The npm package is not there on the typescript website.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `.d.ts` file you've created in the project should also be listed as a part of your project in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "global.d.ts" // << specify your file here
  ],
```

Comment: There is no tsconfig file in the project currently. I am using only js in the project.

Comment: Well, then maybe create one, as long as you want to use TS syntax of course